# How to capitalize and replace characters in shell script in one echo

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace, uppercase

I am trying to find a way to capitalize and replace dashes of a string in one echo. I do not have the ability to use multiple lines for reassigning the string value.

For example:
`string='test-e2e-uber'` needs to `echo $string` as **TEST_E2E_UBER**

I currently can do one or the other by utilizing

`${string^^}` for capitalization

`${string//-/_}` for replacement

However, when I try to combine them it does not appear to work (bad substitution error).
Is there a correct syntax to achieve this?

`echo ${string^^//-/_}`

Comment: I've seen questions about doing two replacements at once and the answer was no, it is not possible. So I'm afraid this combination of `^^` and `//.../...` wont work either. Just do it in two steps with an intermediate assignment.

Comment: You may consider doing it in two steps: `string=${string^^}; string=${string//-/_}`

Comment: If piping through `tr` is an option, you could use `echo "$string" | tr '[:lower:]-' '[:upper:]_'`

Comment: @Balry: How should the string `abüßà` get translated? Or a string containing the French double-vocal _æ_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not answer directly your question, but still following script achieves what you wanted :

```
declare -u string='test-e2e-uber'
echo ${string//-/_}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you dislike it so much to have two successive assignment statements? If you really hate it, you will have to revert to some external program to do the task for you, such as

```
string=$(tr  a-z- A-Z_ <<<$string)
```

but I would consider it a waste of resources to create a child process for such a simple operation.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can do that directly with the 'tr' command, in just one 'echo'

```
echo "$string" | tr "-" "_" | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"
TEST_E2E_UBER
```

I don't think 'tr' allows to do the conversion of 2 objects in one command only, so I used pipe for output redirection

2. or you could do something similar with 'awk'

```
echo "$string" | awk '{gsub("-","_",$0)} {print toupper($0)}'
TEST_E2E_UBER
```

in this case, I'm replacing with 'gsub' the hyphen, then i'm printing the whole record to uppercase

Comment: You should quote both the variable references (`"$string"` instead of just `$string`) and the `[...]` arguments to `tr`, to avoid unexpected parsing/wildcard expansion.